# How do I change the button title with the date value after a date is chosen from React-Native DateTimePicker?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, datetimepicker, react-native-community

Currently the default setting of the button title is 'SELECT DATE', I would like this title to change to 'YYYY-MM-DD' based on the value chosen in the datepicker. I used { selectedDate ? </> : </> } conditioning on the title but it wouldn't change even if I change it to a hard-coded title like 'NEW DATE' as if the condition is never met. What am I missing or doing wrong with the conditioning?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import DateTimePicker from '@react-native-community/datetimepicker';
import { Button, Platform, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';

function AppDatePicker({ selectedDate }) {
    const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
    const [mode, setMode] = useState('date');
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

    const onChange = ({ selectedDate }) => {
        const currentDate = selectedDate || date;
        setShow(Platform.OS === 'ios');
        setDate(currentDate);

        let tempDate = new Date(currentDate);
        let fDate = tempDate.getFullYear() + '-' + (tempDate.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + tempDate.getDate();
        console.log(fDate)
    }

    const showMode = (currentMode) => {
        setShow(true);
        setMode(currentMode);
    }

    return (
        <View>
            <View style={styles.button}>
                {
                    selectedDate ? (
                        <Button
                            onPress={() => showMode('date')}
                            title={fDate.toString()}>
                        </Button>
                    ) : (
                        <Button
                            onPress={() => showMode('date')}
                            title="Select Date">
                        </Button>
                    )
                }
            </View>
            {show && 
                <DateTimePicker
                    value={date}
                    mode={mode}
                    display='default'
                    onChange={onChange}>
                </DateTimePicker>
            }
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    button: {
        margin: 20,
    },
})

export default AppDatePicker;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `selectedDate` is not a state. It is the input parameter of the function `onChange` (and a prop of `AppDatePicker`? I fail to see where this is used in the current code). Since the selected date is represented by the state `date`, you can use this instead.

However, since `date` is never undefined, we need to find another mechanism here. I would create a state that holds the title property and change it according to the picked date.

It seems to me that [the onChange function](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/datetimepicker#onchange-optional) of the component that you are using is receiving two parameters called `event` and `date`. You are destructuring `selectedDate` in your `onChange` function which does not exist.

I have fixed this as well.

Furthermore, it is not necessary to use two button instances if we want to change the title only.

```js
function AppDatePicker() {
    const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
    const [mode, setMode] = useState('date');
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    const [title, setTitle] = useState("Select Date");

    const onChange = (selectedDate) => {
        const currentDate = selectedDate || date;
        setShow(Platform.OS === 'ios');
        setDate(currentDate);

        let tempDate = new Date(currentDate);
        let fDate = tempDate.getFullYear() + '-' + (tempDate.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + tempDate.getDate();
        console.log(fDate)
  
        setTitle(fDate.toString())
    }

    const showMode = (currentMode) => {
        setShow(true);
        setMode(currentMode);
    }

    return (
        <View>
            <View style={styles.button}>
                <Button
                   onPress={() => showMode('date')}
                   title={title}>
                </Button>
            </View>
            {show && 
                <DateTimePicker
                    value={date}
                    mode={mode}
                    display='default'
                    onChange={(_, date) => onChange(date)}>
                </DateTimePicker>
            }
        </View>
    );
}
```